# Gulp in visual studio 2012 with TFS as a source control

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, gulp

So far we aren't using gulp in our MVC project. Now we got new application from vendor and they used SASS and Gulp for task runner. I have installed node, npm, gulp and all dependencies. First I got permission issue because of read only in file but that's solved by gulp-tfs-checkout.

Now My problem is, I have "n" .scss files in source folder(src -> .scss, .scss,.......) and with watch it's updating main.css in destination(dest -> main.css). So "checkout" task in Gulp is cheking out main.css. since it's just one file and it's checked out by me so other developer is not able to edit any of the scss. This is happening in local, and we have dev and beta after that.

How to solve this problem??? **so we can use gulp with VS2012**.

Comment: How do you check out tasks in Gulp?

Comment: I have used gulp-tfs-checkout

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking for [Task Runner Explorer](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8e1b4368-4afb-467a-bc13-9650572db708). But this extension only exists from VS2013, there is no VS 2012 version.